# Compose StateFlow being kept even after ViewModel that creates it is recreated

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm having a real strange issue here. I have a `ViewModel` that has a `StateFlow`. That `ViewModel` is recreated in specific circumstances and sets it's `StateFlow` value to 0.

I also have Compose view that reads value of this `StateFlow` and displays text according to it.
Then I change that state to 2, for example. And then recreate the whole Compose view and `ViewModel`.

But, when I recreate the whole view, and the `ViewModel`, for brief moment, `StateFlow` keeps it's old state (even though `ViewModel` is recreated altogether with the View and state is set to 0), and then switches to the new one, which is zero (this only works if you make a change mentioned below).

This can cause tha crash if we have lists that have different amout of items, and we pass them when view is recreated, because then we will read index value that does not exist and our app will crash.

Changing the list `ViewModelTwo(mutableListOf("text4"))` to the  `ViewModelTwo(mutableListOf("text4", "text5", "text6"))` will stop the crash. But look at the logs, and you'll see what's going on. First it goes to 2, then to 0, which is default.

I have github repo setup for Compose-Jb. You can open it in Android Studio: https://github.com/bnovakovic/composableIssue

Sorry for using android compose tags, but I could not find Compose-JB tag.
And for convinience, here are the code snippets.

Any help is appreciated

**Main.kt**

```
@Composable
@Preview
fun App(viewModelOne: ViewModelOne) {
    val showComposable by viewModelOne.stateOne.collectAsState()

    MaterialTheme {
        // Depending on the state we decide to create different ViewModel
        val viewModelTwo: ViewModelTwo = when (showComposable) {
            0 -> ViewModelTwo(mutableListOf("text1", "text2", "text3"))
            1 -> ViewModelTwo(mutableListOf("text4"))
            else -> ViewModelTwo(mutableListOf("blah1", "blah2", "blah3"))
        }

        // New composable is always created with new ViewModelTwo that has default index of 0, yet the app still crashes
        TestComposableTwo(viewModelTwo)
        Row {
            Button(onClick = {
                viewModelOne.changeState()
            }) {
                Text("Click button below, than me")
            }
        }
    }
}

fun main() = application {
    Window(onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication) {
        val viewModelOne = ViewModelOne();
        App(viewModelOne)
    }
}
```

**TestComposableView**

```
@Composable
fun TestComposableTwo(viewModelTwo: ViewModelTwo) {

    val currentIndex by viewModelTwo.currentListItem.collectAsState()
    println("Index is: $currentIndex")
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .fillMaxHeight()

    ) {
        // At the point where we recreate this composable view, currentIndex keeps it's old value, and then changes it
        // to the new one causing the app to crash since new list does not have index of 1
        Text(text = viewModelTwo.stringList[currentIndex])
        Button(onClick = {
            viewModelTwo.changeIndex()
        }) {
            Text("Click me before clicking button above")
        }
    }

}
```

**ViewModel1**

```
class ViewModelOne {
    private val viewModelScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
    private val _stateOne = MutableStateFlow(0)
    val stateOne = _stateOne.asStateFlow()

    fun changeState() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val currentValue = stateOne.value + 1
            _stateOne.emit(currentValue)
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel2**

```
class ViewModelTwo(val stringList: List<String>) {
    private val viewModelScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
    private val _currentListItem = MutableStateFlow(0)
    val currentListItem = _currentListItem.asStateFlow()

    fun changeIndex() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _currentListItem.emit(2)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems overly complex to make a new ViewModelTwo in the Composable based on a value in the first ViewModel. Try to make your ViewModel take care of the logic and your Composables just show the data.

I would suggest using a single ViewModel with a single MutableStateFlow.
And you don't need the emit or the viewModelScope in this case.
Something like this should work:

```kotlin
class MainViewModel {
    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(State(listOf("text1", "text2", "text3"), 0))
    val state: StateFlow<State> = _state

    fun onChangeStateClick() {
        _state.value = State(listOf("text4"), 0) // Or other logic here if needed
    }

    fun onChangeIndexClick() {
        _state.update {
            if (it.currentIndex < it.stringList.count() - 1) {
                it.copy(currentIndex = it.currentIndex + 1)
            } else it.copy(currentIndex = 0)
        }
    }

    data class State(
        val stringList: List<String>,
        val currentIndex: Int
    )
}
```

```kotlin
@Composable
@Preview
fun App(viewModel: MainViewModel) {
    val state by viewModel.state.collectAsState()

    MaterialTheme {
        TestComposableTwo(
            state.stringList[state.currentIndex],
            onButtonClick = { viewModel.onChangeIndexClick() }
        )
        Row {
            Button(onClick = {
                viewModel.onChangeStateClick()
            }) {
                Text("Click button below, than me")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TestComposableTwo(text: String, onButtonClick: () -> Unit) {

    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .fillMaxHeight()

    ) {
        Text(text = text)
        Button(onClick = onButtonClick) {
            Text("Click me before clicking button above")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Andres, thanks for your answer. This example shows simplified usage case. Complicated apps tend to work differently. And this still does not answer my question on why the sate is being preserved even though everything is recreated. And if there is a way to avoid this :)

Comment: I'll try to answer just that part then: 
`// New composable is always created with new ViewModelTwo that has default` 
I don't think this comment is correct. A Composable only re-renders the parts it needs to re-render, where the input changed.  See https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#skips